# Can't find Model Substance Painter - Lost in the Void

Tags: 3d, camera

I must have zoomed out too far, turned the camera in the wrong direction, whatever. The model is lost, I cannot find it in the 3D View. This is a complex project and I don't want to start over. I have tried orthographic view and all known keyboard shortcuts. But I am still lost in the void and I can't find my 3D Model. I'm about to plant a bomb at Substance Painter HQ or at least give them a phone call wishing death on them all.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F recenters the camera on the object you're editing.